# Memory errors with Ubuntu but not with MemTest86+

Tags: ram, data-corruption

I got some btrfs and ext4 errors. After deciding to test my RAM I got the following repeating errors with `memtester`. I always do get similar errors after a bit of running the `memtester`. Usually in an hour, but it took 4-5 hours in one time.

My computer's RAM is soldered. I got additional empty slot. There are no settings in BIOS to disable on-board RAM.

**I've ran:**

- Memtest86+ for 8 passes (~8 hours)
- MemTest86 for 18 passes (~9 hours)
- `memtester` and `stressapptest` on Fedora 27 default, installed on a USB stick (~10 hours)
- `memtester` and `stressapptest` on Ubuntu 17.10 Live default (~2 hours)
- `memtester` and `stressapptest` on Ubuntu 17.10 on USB stick (~8 hours)
- `# debsums --changed` the only changed file was an image of a theme.

They didn't print any errors.

I am using Ubuntu 17.10 (upgraded from 17.04) with default kernel. Kernel is not tainted. It's an ASUS laptop with Intel Haswell i3.

- Also tested with Linux 4.14.13 and 4.15.0-rc3,rc4, mainline.
- Also tested with purged intel-microcode package.

Error is reproducible either Nouveau is disabled or enabed, no nvidia binary drivers are loaded.

Blacklisted the following modules:  `mtd` `intel_spi_platform` `intel_spi` because they don't load on default Fedora 27 install and they [seem to](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/12/ubuntu-corrupting-lenovo-laptop-bios) brick some Lenova laptops. Errors have not stopped.

`uname -a`'s output

```
Linux hostname 4.13.0-19-generic #22-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 4 11:58:07 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`# lsmod`'s output

https://paste.ubuntu.com/26222245/

Fedora 27's `# lsmod`'s output

https://paste.ubuntu.com/26226473/

### Current Situation

I've put my HDD into a laptop (backup laptop) that I've known to be good and ran the tests there. I got the errors. Now I am pretty sure this is a software issue. I've never been able to trigger the errors on my laptop with a fresh Ubuntu nor with a Fedora trying many many hours.

What should I do?

**A sample of the errors:**

```
Loop 6:
  Stuck Address       : ok         
  Random Value        : ok
  Compare XOR         : ok
  Compare SUB         : ok
  Compare MUL         : ok
  Compare DIV         : ok
  Compare OR          : ok
  Compare AND         : ok
  Sequential Increment: ok
  Solid Bits          : ok         
  Block Sequential    : ok         
  Checkerboard        : ok         
  Bit Spread          : ok         
  Bit Flip            : testing 262
FAILURE: 0x00000000 != 0xfffffffeffffffff at offset 0x0ef94000.
FAILURE: 0x00000000 != 0x100000000 at offset 0x0ef94008.
FAILURE: 0x00000000 != 0xfffffffeffffffff at offset 0x0ef94010.
FAILURE: 0x00000000 != 0x100000000 at offset 0x0ef94018.
FAILURE: 0x00000000 != 0xfffffffeffffffff at offset 0x0ef94020.
FAILURE: 0x00000000 != 0x100000000 at offset 0x0ef94028.
FAILURE: 0x00000000 != 0xfffffffeffffffff at offset 0x0ef94030.
FAILURE: 0x00000000 != 0x100000000 at offset 0x0ef94038.
  Walking Ones        : ok         
  Walking Zeroes      : ok         
  8-bit Writes        : ok
  16-bit Writes       : ok
```

A similar error with the both RAM slots are full:

```
Loop 1:
  Stuck Address       : ok         
  Random Value        : ok
  Compare XOR         : ok
  Compare SUB         : ok
  Compare MUL         : ok
  Compare DIV         : ok
  Compare OR          : ok
  Compare AND         : ok
  Sequential Increment: ok
  Solid Bits          : ok         
  Block Sequential    : ok         
  Checkerboard        : ok         
  Bit Spread          : testing   4
FAILURE: 0x00000000 != 0x00000050 at offset 0x7da80000.
FAILURE: 0x00000000 != 0xffffffffffffffaf at offset 0x7da80008.
FAILURE: 0x00000000 != 0x00000050 at offset 0x7da80010.
FAILURE: 0x00000000 != 0xffffffffffffffaf at offset 0x7da80018.
FAILURE: 0x00000000 != 0x00000050 at offset 0x7da80020.
FAILURE: 0x00000000 != 0xffffffffffffffaf at offset 0x7da80028.
FAILURE: 0x00000000 != 0x00000050 at offset 0x7da80030.
FAILURE: 0x00000000 != 0xffffffffffffffaf at offset 0x7da80038.
  Bit Flip            : setting 141
```

An error of `stressapptest`:

```
Report Error: miscompare : DIMM Unknown : 1 : 157s
Hardware Error: miscompare on CPU 2(0x2) at 0x7fcc0726e000(0xb0d18:DIMM Unknown): read:0x0000000000000000, reread:0x0000000000000000 expected:0x4a4a4a4a4a4a4a4a
Report Error: miscompare : DIMM Unknown : 1 : 157s
Hardware Error: miscompare on CPU 2(0x2) at 0x7fcc0726e008(0xb0d18:DIMM Unknown): read:0x0000000000000000, reread:0x0000000000000000 expected:0x4a4a4a4a4a4a4a4a
Report Error: miscompare : DIMM Unknown : 1 : 157s
Hardware Error: miscompare on CPU 2(0x2) at 0x7fcc0726e010(0xb0d18:DIMM Unknown): read:0x0000000000000000, reread:0x0000000000000000 expected:0x4a4a4a4a4a4a4a4a
Report Error: miscompare : DIMM Unknown : 1 : 157s
Hardware Error: miscompare on CPU 2(0x2) at 0x7fcc0726e018(0xb0d18:DIMM Unknown): read:0x0000000000000000, reread:0x0000000000000000 expected:0x4a4a4a4a4a4a4a4a
Report Error: miscompare : DIMM Unknown : 1 : 157s
Hardware Error: miscompare on CPU 2(0x2) at 0x7fcc0726e020(0xb0d18:DIMM Unknown): read:0x0000000000000000, reread:0x0000000000000000 expected:0x4a4a4a4a4a4a4a4a
Report Error: miscompare : DIMM Unknown : 1 : 157s
Hardware Error: miscompare on CPU 2(0x2) at 0x7fcc0726e028(0xb0d18:DIMM Unknown): read:0x0000000000000000, reread:0x0000000000000000 expected:0x4a4a4a4a4a4a4a4a
Report Error: miscompare : DIMM Unknown : 1 : 157s
Hardware Error: miscompare on CPU 2(0x2) at 0x7fcc0726e030(0xb0d18:DIMM Unknown): read:0x0000000000000000, reread:0x0000000000000000 expected:0x4a4a4a4a4a4a4a4a
Report Error: miscompare : DIMM Unknown : 1 : 157s
Hardware Error: miscompare on CPU 2(0x2) at 0x7fcc0726e038(0xb0d18:DIMM Unknown): read:0x0000000000000000, reread:0x0000000000000000 expected:0x4a4a4a4a4a4a4a4a
```

I suspect somehow Ubuntu's configuration combined with my Laptop's hardware is to blame about these errors. Almost every time in packs of eight.

### Unimportant, loosely related info below

About the btrfs errors; I was using 17.04. I've asked around in btrfs' irc. I've been told that it could be a hardware error or somehow a memory management error. A portion of the metadata page of the btrfs got filled with zeros, just like I've been experiencing now. I did ran memtester just a few passes, switched to ext4 and put the blame on nvidia binary driver.

**The commands and their parameters that I use:**

```
# stressapptest -M 10000 -s 1800
```

10000 is the available memory that I can test. I get it via `free -m`-s` is seconds.

```
# memtester 4096
```

The laptop's CPU has 2 cores so I usually start two instances. 4096
   is half of current available memory via `free -m`

Comment: I would replace bad RAM, but I don't know if it is possible with soldered RAM chips. Is the computer new enough to be replaced within the guarantee?

Comment: @sudodus Yes, its guarantee hasn't expired yet. I'll RMA it if I can't find a solution.  I've found that even though there is no official way, people have found ways to disable soldered rams on some laptops via jumping some test points.

Comment: To be more sure try [`memtest86+`](http://www.memtest.org/#screen) from any Ubuntu installation LiveCD.

Comment: @N0rbert I did some tests with memtest86 -the propitiatory one- with negative results. But they were short -4 reps-, I'll do an overnight test tonight.

Comment: Negative meaning no RAM errors.

Comment: Try without one of the RAM cards (and switch cards). This way you might find that one particular RAM card is faulty (or maybe a slot on the motherboard is faulty, possible but not very likely).

Comment: @sudodus, I've got one solderd, one empty, I get the errors either the extra slot is empty or not.

Comment: Do you get errors, when you run without the removable RAM?

Comment: @sudodus Yes. I do get memtester errors but not MemTest86. Same as with removable RAM.

Comment: So the removable RAM does not add any errors. I don't know memtester, but I know memtest86+. I know that memtest86+ cannot really test a small part of the memory (which is used by the system, when running memtest). Maybe memtester can test that too, maybe not. -- btrfs is a new file system, I think not yet fully developed and debugged, but ext4 is very stable by now. Have you tried to repair your ext4 file system?

Comment: @sudodus, I believe memtest86+ can test its own memory, it shouldn't be that much of an issue however. Yes I've repaired my ext4 partition a few times as it broke probably because of memory related errors. Unfortunately I couldn't repair my btrfs partition as the somehow metadata got corrupted before it has been written to the disk and my btrfs partition probably spread it with btrfs scrub and corrupted some of it.

Comment: Well, at this stage I think you should use the guarantee (and tell the vendor, that there is a problem with the soldered RAM).

Comment: @sudodus But I can't prove there is a problem with the RAM, memtest86 doesn't output any errors, I only have memory errors with Linux. Vendor would probably only test with memtest86 or similar apps/OSes.

Comment: Well, you can tell the vendor about the test with memtester. And the vendor can either accept the result of memtester or not. If you want some confirmation or verification of memtester, you can try to get a dialogue with the person or people, who have created memtester and/or maintain it. Maybe the following link would work for that purpose, http://pyropus.ca/software/memtester/

Comment: @sudodus Thanks, getting in touch with vendor may help, I may do that but I don't think memtester's maintainer could help, I've edit my post to add that `stressapptest` can show some the errors too.

Comment: @sudodus: The memory area that memtest86 can't test is the area reserved for the system firmware. No program can test that area because it is locked to code that runs with fewer privileges than the system firmware, i. e. ring -1. Operating systems and programs like memtest86 run with ring 0 privileges. A specially crafted EFI memory test program may be able to get around that.

Comment: Clearly you have a hardware problem unrelated to Ubuntu.

Comment: @ElderGeek Thanks, Could you please tell me how did you conclude in that? As I've said I could not reproduce the errors neither with Fedora nor with Memtest86+.

Comment: Sure: "Hardware Error: miscompare on CPU 2(0x2)"

Comment: @ElderGeek But I've did the same test on Fedora 27 for hours and it didn't print any errors.

Comment: Any other differences between these tests? Ambient temperature perhaps? Can you duplicate the errors booted off Ubuntu live media? Any difference in the kernel options/versions in use when booting Fedora vs. Ubuntu? Versions of `stressapptest`? Please [edit] any additional details into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @ElderGeek No differences, I don't even move the laptop. I could not duplicate the errors on Live Ubuntu, but I did test the live ubuntu little, I should test live 17.10 a bit more. I can't see why the versions would matter, memtester both 4.3.0, stressapptest 1.0.6 on ubuntu, latest on master branch -self built-. It seems like the ubuntu install is somehow may be the one to blame as the memtest86+ don't put any errors too.

Comment: What arguments are you launching `stressapptest` with?

Comment: @ElderGeek, -M XXX -s 1800,  XXX=available memory (free) - 100M, usually 10000 or so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70693/discussion-between-elder-geek-and-artyom).

Comment: It's a shot in the dark but I would try disabling kaslr using **nokaslr** on the grub boot kernel command line. kaslr has been around as an option since Ubuntu 14.10 but is turned on by default now.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Omg! Thanks, looks like nokaslr stops the memory errors. I've tested with it about 8 hours, got no error, removed the boot parameter and got some in an hour. Now testing it for more. Will report back.

Comment: I'll write up an answer tonight when I get home.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, Bad news, it happened again, but it took quite longer to trigger it, this time it took about 7 hours, I guess I'll let memtes86+ run more than 24h hours.

Comment: Should I hit this with Ubuntu forums? Or a mailing list?

Answer (score 1):

## Deleted answer was close

An answer was deleted on this Q&A:

> Did you already try re-installing ubuntu because it sounds like an OS
> level memory managment failure

My answer is similar as it involves very low level memory management; **KASLR** at the Kernel level.

## What KASLR does

KASLR stands for **K**ernel **A**ddress **S**pace **L**ayout **R**andomization. I've never heard it spoken out-loud but in my mind I pronounce it "Casler". Think friendly ghost in the machine. KASLR is a security measure to randomize which memory locations kernel modules reside. The theory is the kernel is harder to hack when you can't rely on the same bit of code always being in the same memory spot.

KASLR operation could be considered an opposite of memory testers which repetitively read and write to the same memory locations expecting NO CHANGES.  These being opposites, it attracted me (idiom noticed), to do a google search on KASLR and memory errors. One in particular seemingly unrelated might deserve a message on [github](https://github.com/volatilityfoundation/volatility/issues/365) linking to this Q&A. The reason being they think they are the only ones effected by shifting memory addresses (if I'm reading their thread correctly). The first three hits are from **RedHat** who I'm loath to link to because their websites are partial posts to get on google search robots and then they make you pay to read.

There are known problems when KASLR loads kernel "stuff" into into the middle of the memory map which it isn't supposed to do. Unfortunately I can't recall the link I found last week to include in tonight's answer. The link had a patch / workaround for directing KASLR to not use specific memory locations.

After confirming known problems with KASLR and memory locations I commented under the question to disable it KASLR and rerunning memory tests. A reply stated it appears to be successful so I'm posting this answer.

## How to disable KASLR

Although I've been using grub kernel command line option "kaslr" for a couple of years now, it became the kernel default since at least version **4.12**. To eliminate KASLR from loading use edit `/etc/default/grub` and change this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nokaslr"
```

You might have other options besides "quiet" and "splash". The important step is to add "nokaslr" and leave the other options in place.

Then save the file and run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Of course another way of disabling KASLR is to simply use an older Kernel like 4.4.0 under Ubuntu 16.04.1 when KASLR wasn't automatically included.

Answer (score 0):

The problem very much sounds like a random bit corruption of the RAM. In my experience, MemTest86 is "too easy" test for the hardware. It will find really bad memory but slight problems will often go unnoticed.

If you want to know if your memory is good, try running [Prime95](https://www.mersenne.org/download/) in self-test/torture mode configured to use as much RAM as possible.

Another good test is to run double sided rowhammer test for a few hours.

I belive that if Prime95 and double sided rowhammer cannot find any issues with your memory, it probably works correctly. However, simply running MemTest86, compiling programs, installing OS, playing games may appear to work even if your memory is slightly bad (been there, done that - and got corrupted data in long run).

Answer (score -1):

The program memtester does a *malloc()* call to reserve chunks of memory (see "man memtester") in the heap segment. Chunks of Memory a program has reserved with *malloc()* is in the programs own use, and it can do reads and writes in there how it wants (see "man malloc"). Probably almost 100% of Programs use this mechanism themselves or trough a library and **RELY** on the memory there being **EXACTLY** what they wrote into that place before. If this has errors, almost every program including the linux kernel are in big trouble and can not operate correct or stable. This is fundamental. If KASLR was changing this stuff, then safe us god, because then no program could operate anymore. So of course, KASLR **DOES NOT** change any data contents in another programs *malloc()* reservations in the slightest.

So, I think that you probably solved the problem already one way or another, but I still want to give my advice for anybody having a similar problem:

Try some memtest86. If this comes out correct after extensive runtime, then it is likely a problem with the software and you maybe need to reinstall linux. If it detects errors, then it is very likely the hardwares fault.